# Adding StateCode dash StateName to the autocomplete using MVC4.5 and a JsonResult

Tags: json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get the state code to be followed by a dash and the state name using an ajax autocomplete syntax.  I'm using jQuery and jQueryUI and the jQueryUI autocomplete function to attempt this.

I am using this json result:

```
[{"code":"AK","name":"Alaska"},{"code":"AL","name":"Alabama"},
{"code":"AR","name":"Arkansas"},{"code":"AZ","name":"Arizona"},
{"code":"CA","name":"California"}, ... ]
```

And I'm using this jQuery ajax call with an embedded

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/Cats/State/List',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Cat_stateCode').autocomplete(
            {
                source: data.code + '-' + data.name,
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    });
```

The mvc controller JSON Result looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult List()
    {
        return Json(db.States.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

How do I get the auto complete to show:
CA - California
CO - Colarado

If I type out C?  Or does Autocomplete only work with simple json like  {"AK", "AL", "AR" ... }?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
$("#Cat_stateCode").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cat/States/List",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                req_state_part: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.code + ' - ' + item.name,
                        value: item.code
                    }
                }));
                //                            alert("data.code:" + data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("e.error:" + e.error);
            }
        });
    },

    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //alert("ui item:" + ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);  //todo: remove after dev 
    },

    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },

    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

In my mvc CatStateController I have this:

```
public JsonResult List(String stateAbbreviation)
{
    String StateNameORStateCodeContains = Request.Params["req_state_part"];
    return Json(db.States.Where(state => state.name.Contains(StateNameORStateCodeContains) || state.code.Contains(StateNameORStateCodeContains)).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So it looks like it doesn't sent the term over, it only send over some params you make up in the data element.  Since you can make up pretty much anything its up to the developers imagination.  One thing I was trying to do was create a closure b/c I have a lot of different animals with different states.  And I need to create this same autocomplete function for each of them.   So I need to ask another question how do you remove the auto complete so I can call that same function from many different ids, or do I just separate them out with a comma like so:
$("#Cat_stateCode,#Dog_stateCode,#Penguin_stateCode...").autocomplete({ ...   ???

And I believe the answer to the second part is in [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/Q_26568440.html).   I think its insinuating just add some class or attribute to the applicable input tags and then just perform an each over them and them lastly apply the autocomplete to the $(this).autocomplete immediately after each each iteration occurs.

Found a better way with just set the input tag to have a class="cssClassName". Had to use the TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cat.stateCode,  new { @class = "StateCodeAutoComplete" })
```